# Delete the first "#" character in a String - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I can delete the first "#" character of a string?

#### Example:

```
"fooo#oooooo#bar"
```

#### Expected result:

```
"fooooooooo#bar"

"fooo#oooooo#bar".delete_first("#") // Exist some method like this?
```

Comment: The downvote is because you need to show effort before asking others to do your work.

Comment: Sorry, but in my point of view StackOverflow is a huge community. I can find the solution by my own way, that's right, but about the other people who have the same question? It can be a dumb question, but you never hear about all the questions is valid? A lot of people can be helped by my question and by the friends who answered this questions. thanks to everyone, including you - I'll take more care next time

Comment: Just to be exact, I wasn't the one who downvoted. I just clarified the most likely reason, why somebody else did that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) (not `gsub`) does that:

```
"fooo#oooooo#bar".sub('#', '') #=> "fooooooooo#bar"
```